# REGEX - How To Match Two String WIthin x Chars of Each Other

Tags: regex

I am using software which uses regular expressions to search text files.  Files matching the regular expression are then made available for inspection.

I need to search for cases where two strings must be present, and the second string must  occur after the first string, but no more than x chars after the first.  In this case, the last character of the second string is always an apostrophe.

For example, looking for string one "ABC" and string two "XY'" where string two must begin no more than 5 places after the end of string one:

```
"ABCxxxxXY" // match

"ABCxxxxxxxxxXY" // not a match.
```

Another, maybe better, way to look at this would be to define a match as containing string one, then containing "XY" immediately preceding the next apostrophe.

```
"ABCxxxxxxxxXY" // match.

"ABCxxxxxxxxx'xxxxxXY" // not a match.
```

Thanks

Mike Thomas

Comment: Did you find a relevant answer? The examples you have seem to contradict one another so that may be causing confusion.

Comment: `where string two must begin no more than 5 spaces after the end of string one`. Did you mean _places_ instead of _spaces_ ?

Comment: I see you've submitted a suggested edit to Shiplu's answer.  It should be applied to the question instead.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I edited the prompt already to reflect the suggested change.

Comment: @user772047 - If any of these answers satisfies the question please select one as the correct answer so that this question can be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> looking for string one "ABC" and string two "XY'" where string two must begin no more than 5 spaces after the end of string one

This would do.

```
 /ABC.{1,5}XY/
```

---

> Another, maybe better, way to look at this would be to define a match as containing string one, then containing "XY" immediately preceeding the next apostrophe.

You need this,

```
 /ABC[^']*'.*(?=XY)XY/
```

Comment: I think he *meant* **places**.

Comment: Yes. I think that's what the OP meant.

Comment: Shiplu, the first one, /ABC.{1,5}XY/ works exactly right.  I have to play with the second one.  Many thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying an exact number of matches in between.

`^ABC.{0,5}XY$`

This says "Match anything starting with ABC and having 0-5 repetitions of any type of character ending in XY."

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how many characters might be between the two strings.  It would always be at least two, but could be as many as 30.  MT

Comment: Then you can change it from {2,30}. Regex will just match the number of characters specified in the range. You may have more luck getting a relevant answer if you post what you're actually doing instead of a simplified case.

Comment: Also, side note, if you know the types of characters it would be better to use that then `.`. `.` will match any character including newline and symbols, which may be undesirable. An example replacement would be `[A-Za-z1-9]` which will match any alphanumeric character.

Comment: Thanks Michael - This one works if I remove the leading ^ and trailing $

Answer (score 0):

```
/ABC[^\']{0,5}XY'/
```

should match your second question.